# How to change Windows drive left storage bar

Tags: windows-10, icons, storage, themes

I wanted to ask how I could change the bar over disks that shows how much storage is in use. I wanted to know how could I change Properties Theme from a light version to a dark mode style?

I hope you can help me because Google doesn't really help and I can't find anything.

The bar I am talking about:
[image]

I want to change from
[image: this]
to kind of this
[image: this]

Comment: Just enable the dark theme within Windows.  If you are not offered that theme, as it's a feature of specific Windows 10 versions, you will have to upgrade to that version in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Muddyblack k: See **dark setting** on the **Colors** tab:  [Change desktop background and colors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-desktop-background-and-colors-176702ca-8e24-393b-15f2-b15b38f69de6)

Comment: I already have dark mode activated it did change explorer etc... but for the properties windows it stays white

Comment: Only Microsoft can solve this badly-made dark mode. You are not alone and this is not the only place. See [Dark Mode broken in many places in Windows 10 20H2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_theme/dark-mode-broken-in-many-places-in-windows-10-20h2/23c51272-98c3-4c53-903c-ed15dfeca03f).

Comment: @Muddyblackk - I am confused.  Did you make the second screenshot of the properties menu yourself or something?

Comment: @ Ramhound no I did find it  [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/mys49h/can_we_get_a_dark_mode_file_explorer_properties/) sad no one knows how do that :D well its windows hehe ^^ but still does someone know how you can change the storage bar of the Driver Disks?

Comment: But there are Themes like [this](https://www.deviantart.com/niivu/art/xTheme-for-Windows-10-816289887) and I would like to write one by myself but however there is no one explaining it. All you can find is to change it in Windows settings what is ridiculous xD

Comment: But maybe it is better to let it how it is to not break Windows in the next Update ^^